# How can I select a string with the following pattern using RegEx with Python?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I'm looking for specific structures in my text data. One of these is creating many problems; look the following toy sentence:

"As you can see by reading point a) and b), someone could even use lect. A), B) and Z)."

My goal is to use a RegEx which can find structures representing items list, where the items are represented with the use of ALPHA+PARENTHESES.

Even if it might not be the best solution, I thought that one way could be defining the following pattern:

WORD + ALPHA) + xx + ALPHA) where "xx" represent all the sequence of characters (including symbols and spaces) between ALPHA) and ALPHA) which does not contain more than 3 alpha characters in sequence. 
How can I do it using RegEx?
Anyone with some ideas to deal with such a problem?

In the shown example I would like to get:

- "point a) and b)"
- "lect. A), B) and Z)"

I have to say I'm not so skilled in using RegEx.

I hope I made the problem clear.
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: Show us your attempt(s) to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly what you're looking for without seeing examples of what you've tried compared against the output you expect.

That said, I believe that the pattern `r"\w+(\.){,1} [a-zA-Z]\)(( |\,)[a-zA-Z]{,3} [a-zA-Z]\))*"` might be helpful (note, I am by no means a RegEx expert, and there is probably a more concise way of writing this).

For a detailed explanation, please see here: https://regex101.com/r/j8C09i/3

The short version of what this pattern does is as follows:

- `\w+(\.){,1}` matches a word (`a-Z` and/or `0-9`) followed by zero or one periods and then a space. In other words, this matches the `WORD` part of the `WORD + ALPHA) + xx + ALPHA)` pattern you're looking for.
- `[a-zA-Z]\)` matches a letter followed by a right parenthesis. In other words, this matches the `ALPHA)` part of the pattern.
- `(( |\,)[a-zA-Z]{,3} [a-zA-Z]\))*` matches a space or comma, then a word of at most length 3, then a space, then another letter followed by a right parenthesis, repeated zero or more times. In other words, this matches the `xx + ALPHA)` part of the pattern.